# How to trigger Railtie initializers in my tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, initialization, railtie

I have my own gem, and my railtie looks like...

```
class MyRailtie < Rails::Railtie
  initializer "my_railtie.configure_rails_initialization" do
    # some initialization behavior
  end
end
```

and I'm trying to test it, but in the tests the initializer never gets called. And I notice I have some dependences in another gems that have an initializer as well and they doesn't get called either.

Do you know what should I do besides require the file?

Comment: Try Rails.application.initialize!

Comment: Rails.application is nil

Answer (score 8):

Since initializers are part of Rails' functionality, you'll need to load that Railtie into a Rails application in order for it to be invoked automatically. This is usually done by building a small Rails app inside your spec folder, but that's a pain to set up by hand. Luckily, there's an excellent gem called [combustion](https://github.com/pat/combustion) which makes testing engines (or gems with railties) a breeze. It will take care of setting up that Rails app for you, and ensure your tests run in that Rails environment (including running that initializer).

Comment: Do we really need a dummy app? I've seen some gems doesn't need it, and still require rails.

Comment: It depends what functionality of Rails your gem uses. Since you want to test the initializers, it's unfortunately pretty hard to run them in isolation -- the [run_initializers method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Initializable.html#method-i-run_initializers) has undocumented arguments and likely expects a Rails application. Technically, you could figure all that out, but I think it'd be messier and more brittle than using `combustion`. You could also move the code in your initializer to a method, call that method from your tests, and just trust that the Railtie works as expected.

Comment: I dig the Combustion gem! Very nice. Far less "scaffolding" for the "rails app" :) +1

Answer (score 7):

In a `before` or `setup` block in your tests you can do something like this:

## For a Railtie

```
MyRailtie::Railtie.initializers.each(&:run)
```

## For an Engine

```
MyEngine::Engine.initializers.each(&:run)
```